# Installing git on Windows 10, unable to access .gitconfig

Tags: windows, git, bash, windows-10

I'm new to git, and i'm trying to install git 2.9.2 from [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win). In the installation (the last of the many) i chose to run it from bash only. I now try to set it up, and the first thing i try is to set my name with

```
$ git config --global user.name "My Name"
```

But after i execute this, i get:

```
fatal: unable to access 'C:\Program Files\Git\ C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile/.config/git/config': Invalid argument
```

Let's say that i now want to clone a repository. I insert something like:

```
git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git
```

But i get:

```
fatal: unable to access 'D:\TestRepo\ C:\Users\username/.config/git/config': Invalid argument
```

I thought that the .gitconfig file should be inside the `C:/Users/username` directory, but it tries to locate `C:\Users\username/.config/git/config`, which seems a little weird. My HOME variable is %USERPROFILE%, as it should. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Right, try and run following git command `git config --global core.autocrlf = true` and let me know what output you get.

Comment: I get 'fatal: unable to access `C:\Program Files\Git\ C:\Users\username/.config/git/config: Invalid argument`
'

Comment: Do you run it with administrators rights? What does `set HOMEPATH` output?

Comment: I did, nothing changed. `set HOMEPATH` returns `HOMEPATH=\Users\username`, as expected. I also tried to manually create a `C:\Users\username/.config/git/config/.gitconfig` empty file, but nothing changed.

Comment: This is strange, try completely removing git from the system and reinstalling it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i guess my lack of knowledge over basic things made me look stupid...

**I just had to delete the HOME environmental variable** and all worked like charm. I don't even remember why i had a HOME variable set (isn't that a linux thing?)

Anyway thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. But if I run with command shell (not bash) with Admin level, `git config --global -l` works.  My git version **2.25.0.windows.1**

I noticed that in the System Info gui of Windows, the env variables for System had a HOME entry of %USERPROFILE%.  But, the User env variables did not.  I added HOME to that too.

Now it works. You'd think the System env would fill in for those not in User.  Maybe something else is going on.

Comment: What is your git? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `git init` on the folder you are trying to operate from?

Also you need to configure your username and the email to your github account for it to work properly.

```
git config --global user.name "username"

git config --global user.email "email@gmail.com"
```

Finally, if you have a space in your name please remember to escape it. ex: "my name" = "my\ name"

did you set up your remote repository?

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/rodoggx/yourRepository.git
```

Comment: The question does not mention Github. Remember that Git is not Github. They are two completely different entities. If any, the question mentions BitBucket.